# Installing Wine on Linux Mint Debian Edition

Tags: linux, debian, wine, linux-mint

For whatever reason, Wine is not in the repository on LMDE. I would like to know how to install it. Can anyone provide instructions on how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**wine** is already available in Linux Mint Debian Edition repository 
you can install it by

```
sudo apt-get update
sud apt-get install wine1.3
```

[Here is a guide](http://www.fandigital.com/2012/05/install-latest-wine-in-debian-linux.html) to get latest version of wine in LMDE

1. **Download all binary (.deb)**

   You can download the packages from [here.](http://dev.carbon-project.org/debian/wine-unstable/) The page provides *.deb packages for  amd64 and i386 architecture. Download only the packages suitable for your machine. Place them in one folder.
   .

2.**Pre-installation**:

Install required dependencies
    Do this if you don't want to see an error message saying something like broken dependencies. You can skip this step though, you can fix it later (after WINE installation) by using Synaptic or by running `sudo apt-get install -f`. FYI, from my exprerience, a WINE library need a package called oss-compat_2 to be installed first.

3.**Install WINE packages**

- Install WINE library

  Run this command in Terminal:

  `sudo dpkg -i libwine*`
- Install WINE binary
  Run this command in Terminal:

  `sudo dpkg -i wine-bin-unstable*`
- Install WINE application
  Run this command in Terminal:

  `sudo dpkg -i wine-unstable*`
- If you encounter dependencies error while installing WINE, try run this command in Terminal:

  `sudo apt-get install -f`

4.**Install WINE Gecko**

This is optional. If you need running an internet based application like a browser in WINE, you need to have a package called "Wine Gecko". You can download it from here. After downloading the app, move or copy it to /usr/share/wine/gecko/ (create the folder if not exist; root previlage needed). This way, you have WINE Gecko available for all users.
    You can also choose to let WINE download it for you, but the downloaded file will be used only for current user, and also it will be removed when you remove .wine folder in you home directory.

Comment: When I ran sudo apt-get install wine, what I got back was this:

Comment: ~ $ sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wine' has no installation candidate

Comment: I have now downloaded all 16 deb packages from the link you provided but am not experienced enough to proceed with the terminal commands as you have them written. In other words, how does it know where I saved the downloads?

Comment: Before proceeding ,try sudo apt-get install wine1.3

Comment: To install downloaded debs first use cd /path/tothe/download/directory

Comment: I made a go of the Wine install, so for that I am grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Requires libmpg123-0 update.

http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/i386/libmpg123-0/download